# asymmetrical multidimensional arrays in c

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, multidimensional-array, porting

I'm porting a piece of code from PHP to c/objective-c, and I'm running into trouble handling this two dimensional array.

```
$PATTERN_LOOKUP = array(
    array(),
    array(6, 18),
    array(6, 22, 38),
    array(6, 26, 46, 66),
    array(6, 28, 50, 72, 94)
);
```

This is the closest I've gotten (it compiles), however I'm thinking I'll run into trouble later, because this is actually a 5x5 array, and there will be a bunch of undefined numbers. Is there a way to make an asymmetrical multidimensional array in c?

```
static int PATTERN_LOOKUP[][5] = {
    {0},
    {6, 18},
    {6, 22, 38},
    {6, 26, 46, 66},
    {6, 28, 50, 72, 94}
};
```

Comment: symmetric is the wrong term. Symmetric is used for a square matrix that is its own transpose. The correct term here is ragged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can always make a "symmetrical" array in C (i.e. a rectangular array) and only use an "asymmetrical" portion of it. This is a perfectly good solution for small arrays. And this is actually exactly what your declaration of `PATTERN_LOOKUP` does (the elements not explicitly initialized will be implicitly initialized with zeros).

However, for larger arrays it might get too expensive in therms of wasted memory. If it does get too expensive, you can always use a "simulated" 2D array in C (an array of pointers to subarrays)

```
static int array0[] = { 0 };
static int array1[] = { 6, 18 };
static int array2[] = { 6, 22, 38 };
static int array3[] = { 6, 26, 46, 66 };
static int array4[] = { 6, 28, 50, 72, 94 };

static int *const PATTERN_LOOKUP[] = {
  array0,
  array1,
  array2,
  array3,
  array4
};
```

You can even use a `NULL` entry in `PATTERN_LOOKUP` array to represent an empty array

```
static int *const PATTERN_LOOKUP[] = {
  NULL,
  array1,
  array2,
  array3,
  array4
};
```

In C99 you can use compound literals to achieve the same result without separate subarray declarations

```
static int *const PATTERN_LOOKUP[] = {
  (int []) { 0 },
  (int []) { 6, 18 },
  (int []) { 6, 22, 38 },
  (int []) { 6, 26, 46, 66 },
  (int []) { 6, 28, 50, 72, 94 }
};
```

Of course, it remains your responsibility to store/remember the actual size of each individual subarray.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thanks very much for all the detail!

Comment: Don't forget that in C99 you can use sizeof and variable length arrays for a very effective solution to this.

Comment: @drewk could you elaborate? that sounds like something I want!

Comment: @Kenny Winker: This answer covers it mostly, but under C99 both arrays and the `sizeof` those arrays can be used dynamically. You could allocate dynamically the size of each row in your X x X array. Under C, `sizeof` is determined at compile time. Under C99, you can do `n=24; int array[n]; size=sizeof(array);` size is then `n * sizeof(int)` It is a great, but potentially evil shortcut. Works great as long as you have enough stack, but most implementations do not check for stack overflow. So it is an effective stack based shortcut of the usual `malloc / free` heap version